# How to fix "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header()"

Tags: php, wordpress, function, fatal-error

I am trying to put this website back online. The error message is the following:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header()
>   in
>   /homepages/25/d584099293/htdocs/clickandbuilds/X3DSYSTEMS/wp-content/themes/x3dprotheme/index.php:4
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /homepages/25/d584099293/htdocs/clickandbuilds/X3DSYSTEMS/wp-content/themes/x3dprotheme/index.php
>   on line 4

The client told me he "accidentally reset the domain".

First when I went on the website, I had an error message about Wordfence and I did what I needed to do to correct it (here what I did:

*[After moving a site or deleting some files, I see: PHP Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required /var/www/html/wordfence-waf.php](https://docs.wordfence.com/en/After_moving_a_site_or_deleting_some_files%2C_I_see__PHP_Fatal_error__Unknown__Failed_opening_required_/var/www/html/wordfence-waf.html)*

I removed the firewall setup manually.

Then I got this new error message about `index.php`:

In this index.php, here is what I found:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I try to get this website back online.

The webhost is 1and1 IONOS. I can't log into WP, but I have SFTP access.

Comment: What about restoring a backup?

Comment: I asked the client to do so because I don't have access to the host but he kind of refused it. The host told him they can't do anything about it (?!)

Answer (score 0):

What webhost is this? Maybe if we know, we can ascertain what the "domain reset" involved and backtrack the fix once we know exactly what those steps entailed.

When these sorts of things happen to me (I manage about 30 WordPress sites), the first thing I do is disable all plugins, and sometimes if I can't actually log into WordPress, I remove the plugins via SFTP or through [cPanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel).

You're stuck though if you have no access to the host. It'll extremely difficult to solve this without access to the server or control panel for the hosting environment. Do you at least have SFTP access?

Comment: the webhost is 1and1 IONOS. I can't log into WP. I have sftp access yes. I can ask for control panel access I guess if it can help

Comment: Temporarily rename each plugin folder and see if this makes any difference in error messages that you get. Also, rename the theme folder temporarily to see if WP will use the default theme correctly. I would want to see if this issue is truely with the active theme or a WP core file. I would definitely ask for control panel access since you very well may need to update the db manually.

Comment: Thanks Dinos, I am getting back to my client today trying to see what I can do. I am also going to contact the webhost to have some informations about the "domain reset". Getting back here as soon as I have new informations.

Comment: Let me/us know what happens and how we can help further. Navigating this can be daunting since there are so many variables.

Comment: The client changed the "target" with his webhost and the site is back online. When he reseted the domain, he changed the target of the website, the "type of use" of the domain. This is the word used in french but I don't exactly know how to translate it in english.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for letting us know Alice! If I've helped at all, I'd love for you to check the box to the left of my initial answer. See this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a path to a core theme file.

If you are using child theme, you should be able to update the parent via the theme settings found in your dashboard, without data loss from style sheets, etc. you made in your child theme.

This would work like the backup restore as suggested above, but without the need to get into cPanel or FTP.

Comment: I didn't do any work on this website, the client doesn't work anymore with his last webmaster so I have no idea what he did here. I can say that I haven't seen any child-folder.

Comment: I think that the theme had been created by the webmaster.

Answer (score 0):

The client changed the "target" with his webhost, and the site is back online.

There was also a problem with revolution slider, but anyway, the problem looks solved.